# How to pass an array as the function parameter?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, dapp-development, dapps

I meet the same problem as this question:
[Passing an array as a parameter from javascrpt (web3) to a Solidity function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8362/passing-an-array-as-a-parameter-from-javascrpt-web3-to-a-solidity-function)

If I call my function in the browser-solidity with the parameter [122,44], it works well. 
But if I use it in my own web UI, it throw out "Error: new BigNumber() not a number".
The way I call it is like:

```
myContract.myFunction([122,44],{from:accounts[0]},function(err,res){...})
```

or

```
myContract.myFunction(["122","44"],{from:accounts[0]},function(err,res){...})
```

I don't know why. It should be the same result as in the browser-solidiy.

Answer (score 1):

What types your solidity function expects? If it's uint or int then you must convert your params to BigNumber before you passing it.
E.g.:

```
import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';
let myParams = [122,44];
let convertedParams = myParams.map( item => { return new BigNumber(item)});
myContract.myFunction(convertedParams,{from:accounts[0]},function(err,res){...})
```